# regex for identifying asp.net (and others) controls in source text

Tags: c#, regex

I am looking for some help to get an expression which I can use to search for

Ignoring all attributes apart from the ID which I would want to extract. Basically, I am looking to enumerate all controls on a page, grabbing their ID and type.

Thanks for any help

Comment: You should look at an ASP.NET markup parser first, and use regex only as a last resort. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/984435/how-does-asp-net-parse-pages for ideas.

Comment: Can you provide us with some of your current code and maybe an example of what you would like to capture?

Comment: sure... 
string patternstart = Regex.Escape("Session[");
string patternend = Regex.Escape("]");
string regexexpr = patternstart + @"(.*?)" + patternend;
I use this to extract stuff from the code behind. I need to get something for the aspx page that ignores all possible tags in the control markup such as cssClass etc, but lets me get the control type and ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about

```
<asp:(\w+)\s+.*?id="(\w+)"
```

Where the first group is the control type and the second one is its id. You can see a working example [here](http://rubular.com/r/lKSdtyZdUB) (the page was taken from an example found on the msdn).

Comment: Perfect... just what I wanted!  One day I'll get to grips with regex!

Comment: @user2744609 it's just a matter of practise ;)

Comment: Hi Can you tell me if I need to extract only text after colon means if `<asp:Label --------- />` I need to get only `Label`

Comment: @Dotnet using the same regex I posted take match.Groups[0]